# hard problem with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

i want RewriteRule to make this
from

```
file.php?var_1=xx&var_2=xx
```

to

```
file/var_1?var_2=xxx
```

Comment: Do you mean literally xx,xx or are they just place holders? If placeholders as I expect, given your result has three xxx how is the value caculated from xx and xx? (and similarly for var_1, var_2 - are they named that or is this supposed to work with all variable names)?

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this so don't know if the following works, but the regex tests correctly

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^file.php\?var_1\=(.+)\&var_2\=(.+)$ file/var_1?var_2=$2 [NC]
```